# Setting and Getting DHCP option for Windows in C#

Tags: c#, windows, dhcp

Using C#, I'm trying to set dhcp option 12 using [ManageDHCP.dll](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ManageDHCP-Manage-your-6bb4f69f).  In a nutshell, this is what I'm doing:

```
var dhcpManager = new DHCPManager(dhcpServerName)
var hostRecord = new HostInfo
               {
                  Name = deviceDhcpName,
                  IPv4 = deviceIpAddress,
                  IsReserved = true,
                  MAC = deviceMacAddress
               };

dhcpManager.SetRecord(dhcpServerScope, hostRecord);

String hostName = deviceDhcpName + "." + dnsZoneName;
var hostnameOpt = new Option
                  {
                     ID = 12,
                     Values = new List<string> { hostName }
                  };
dhcpManager.SetOption(hostnameOpt, dhcpServerScope, deviceIpAddress);
```

The thing is, is that it just dies at this point and the logs don't record an exception.  So I was thinking maybe the format I'm sending it is not correct.  So I went to try and get an option.  So instead, after creating the reservation, with `SetRecord` function above - I called this instead, just to try an see if I could get an option to see the correct format:

```
Option test = dhcpManager.GetOption(3, dhcpServerScope, deviceIpAddress);
```

Which throws this exception:

> ManageDHCP.DhcpException: DhcpGetOptionInfo
>      at ManageDHCP.DHCPManager._GetOption(OptionTarget target, UInt32 optionID, String subnet, String reservedIP)

I'm new to C# and I'm not really sure what's causing this exception.  [Here](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/2D9CB56/4548B3E2) is a link to the source code for ManageDHCP.  What am I doing wrong?  Is my format incorrect?

Comment: Does the sample code work which is provided at the page you linked to?

Comment: Which link? The second link is the source code for the library linked in the first link.  It's not really showing how to use it.

Comment: Your first link: [ManageDHCP - Manage your DHCP server from Powershell and ASP.NET](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ManageDHCP-Manage-your-6bb4f69f). There's a code sample at the end.

Comment: It's not really relevant to what I want to do, which is set the option and create a record, which I thought I was providing the right arguments.  The getting is just to check the format, which for some reason enumOptions works with the variables I provided, so I see all the option elements, so at least I'm getting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the 32-bit dll's setOption function does not work (DhcpGetOptionInfo throws an exception), so I switched to 64 bit dll.